# UEFI SysPrep apps are never launched

Tags: uefi

According to the UEFI spec (Version 2.7 Errata A), section 3.1.7 ("Required System Preparation Applications"):

> "The platform is required to examine all SysPrep#### variables referenced in SysPrepOrder. If Attributes bit LOAD_OPTION_ACTIVE is set, and the application referenced by FilePathList[0] is present, the UEFI Applications thus identified must be loaded and launched in the order they appear in SysPrepOrder and prior to the launch of any load options of type Boot####."

However, in experiments with a simple "hello world + press any key" UEFI app, I have not found any PC that will execute the app when I install it as a SysPrep boot variable.

For example:

- Ubuntu is installed on a test PC with a single HDD, GPT partitioned, UEFI-boot.
- Using EFI shell, copy a test app "hello.efi" from UFD (fs1:) to fs0:\EFI\hello.efi
- Boot to Ubuntu and use efibootmgr to add a sysprep variable:

> sudo efibootmgr -y –create –disk /dev/sda –part 1 –loader /EFI/hello.efi –label "hello" –verbose

Result:

> SysPrepOrder: 0000
>
> SysPrep0000* hello     HD(1,GPT,f440c17d-...c72d,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\hello.efi)

- Reboot PC, and let it boot normally.
- The "hello.efi" SysPrep app does not run before the OS starts booting.

On each PC I have tested, I verified that the EFI BootOptionSupport variable has bit 4 set (0x10), indicating EFI_BOOT_OPTION_SUPPORT_SYSPREP.

Regarding another quote from UEFI spec section 3.1.7:

> "When launched, the platform is required to provide the application loaded by SysPrep####, with the same services such as console and network as are normally provided at launch to applications referenced by a Boot#### variable."

This seems to me that any EFI app that will run as a Boot#### variable, will also run as a SysPrep#### variable.  Is this correct?

On each PC I have tested, the hello.efi app does run from a Boot#### variable (using same efibootmgr command as above, without "-y"), but never runs as a SysPrep#### variable.

Comment: Does any of the platforms you have tested on claim to support UEFI 2.5 or later?

Comment: @unixsmurf - Using the EFI shell command "ver", the primary platform I am testing on says "EFI Specification Revision: 2.50".  I haven't checked the others yet (at another site).  Do SysPrep apps require 2.5 or later?

Comment: Yeah. So something that claims to be 2.5 really ought to implement it. But it doesn't absolutely have to. EDK2 has supported it since 2015.

Comment: @unixsmurf - So one possible reason I can't get SysPrep apps to work is because it isn't really supported on these platforms - even though they set the EFI_BOOT_OPTION_SUPPORT_SYSPREP bit in BootOptionSupport?  Just curious, have you ever successfully used a SysPrep app - and if so, on what type of PC and BIOS?

Comment: @unixsmurf - I just tested on a platform that reports it is EFI rev 2.6 and has EFI_BOOT_OPTION_SUPPORT_SYSPREP, and I have the same problem as above:  SysPrep app is never launched.    It seems more likely to me that I must be doing something wrong, rather than none of these PC's really support SysPrep.